# GPU ->CPU Memcpy failed in tensorflow word2vec in gpu occured

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, gpu, memcpy, word2vec

**I I am studying word2vec of tensorflow.
We bought two 1080i for parallel processing of gpu.
Mounting was successful and p2p was successful.
However, I tried to assign it to gpu using the command with tf.device ('/ gpu: 0')
The following error occurs :**

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 1 with properties:

name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.645

pciBusID 0000:66:00.0

Total memory: 10.91GiB

Free memory: 10.21GiB

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 1

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y Y

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 1:   Y Y

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0)

I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:66:00.0)

I word2vec_kernels.cc:246] Data file: data/spouse_freebase/input2.nt contains 34966827 bytes, 2620786 words, 11769 unique words, 11769 unique frequent words.

E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1276] failed to enqueue async memcpy from device to host: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE; host dst: 0x104d5000000; GPU src: 0x7f12c800cbc0; size: 8=0x8

I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:1338] stream 0x39c2160 did not wait for stream: 0x39bf9a0

I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:3775] stream 0x39c2160 did not memcpy device-to-host; source: 0x3bd0d00

**F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_util.cc:296] GPU->CPU Memcpy failed**

I think this error is the out of memory of the gpu.
I wait for your help.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I've just switched off G-SYNC support in Nvidia settings and it helped.